# Explanation of Vector Images

Tags: image, vector-graphics

I was given a ten thousand by sixty four matrix of integers 1, 2, ..., 16 for identification via some programs I wrote earlier. This matrix represents ten thousand eight by eight vectorized images.

My questions aren't so much about how to identify them (I already got that part covered), but rather, more about the data I'm looking at. A brief .txt file with the matrix gave me a little bit of explanation:

> Thirty two by thirty two bitmaps are divided into nonoverlapping blocks of four by four and the number of pixels are counted in each block. This generates an input matrix of eight by eight where each element is an integer in the range 
>   0, . . . , 16.

I'm still a bit confused though. How does a thirty two by thirty two bitmap correspond to a eight by eight image? What does each integer represent? How would I go about converting a given image into a vector image, and then creating it into an array? What is the relationship between a bitmap and the picture in this context?

Thanks for any information or pointers you can give!

Answer (score 0):

A wild guess...

**Step 1)** Take a 4 pixel x 4 pixel image. Each pixel can be black or white. You count the number of, say, black pixels and you will get a number between 0 and 16.

**Step 2)** Now, imagine you have a 32 pixel by 32 pixel image, and you divide it into squares of 4 pixels by 4 pixels - each square being one of the sqaures in Step 1  above. You will get 64 squares, that is, 8 by 8. For each of the 64 squares, store the number between 0-16 from Step 1.

Comment: "Each pixel can be black or white..." - the images are colored though, which throws me off.

"32 pixel by 32 pixel image.." - Can you explain how a bitmap corresponds to a pixel? I don't have a lot of familiarity with graphics.

Comment: A bitmap just means a grid of pixels. As there will always be 16 pixels in a 4x4 block, the phrase *"the number of pixels are counted in each block"* must mean you are counting some *aspect* of the pixels, like whether they are red or black, rather than counting the actual number of pixels.